# Line integral in a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, curves, vector-fields

I have the following question:

Determine the total flux of the velocity field

$$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
x + y
\end{pmatrix}$$

out of the disk $D$, a circle with radius 2 and center at the origin

The answer is:

the Boundary of this disk $D \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ may be parametrized by

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cos t \\
2 \sin t
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{for} \quad 0\leq t \leq 2\pi$$

Thus we have $$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \sin t \\
2 \cos t
\end{pmatrix}dt$$
and
$$ds = ||\vec{ds}|| = 2dt \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The outer unit normal vector a time (or angle) $t$ is given by

$$\vec{n}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos t \\
\sin t
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Which mathematical axiom / theorem do we have to invoke to be able to state (1) and (2)

Comment: $ds$ comes from the arc length formula.

Answer (score 1):

The flux of a closed curved $\boldsymbol{\gamma}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by the formula:
$$\oint_{\gamma} \left < \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{\hat{n}}\right> ds \;\;\;(1)$$

Where $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity field, $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit normal of $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$ and $<.,.>$ is the dot product.

As the comments suggested $ds$ is the infinitesimal arc-length of the curve, which is given by:
$$ds = |\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}| dt$$

And $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ can be thought as the left/right rotation of the unit tangent vector of the curve:
$$\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{R}\mathbf{\hat{t}}$$

Where $\mathbf{\hat{t}}$ is the unit tangent vector, and  $\mathbf{R}$  is the rotation matrix, that rotates a vector to the right.

So,
$$\mathbf{\hat{t}} = \frac{\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}}{|\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}|}$$
and
$$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0& 1\\ 
 -1&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore (1) becomes:
$$\oint_{\gamma} \left < \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{\mathbf{R}\mathbf{\hat{t}}}\right> |\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}| dt$$
$$\oint_{\gamma} \left < \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{\mathbf{R}\frac{\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}}{|\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}|}}\right> |\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}| dt$$

Taking the scalar inside the dot product:

$$\oint_{\gamma} \left < \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}}\right> |\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}|/ |\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}| dt$$

$$\oint_{\gamma} \left < \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{\dot\gamma}}\right> dt$$

Using the info above, I can answer your questions:

Note that $\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
 2\cos(t)\\ 
 2\sin(t) 
\end{bmatrix}$ then:

$$ds = |\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}| dt = \sqrt{\left(2\cos(t)\right)^2 + \left(2\sin(t)\right)^2} dt = \sqrt{4\cos^2(t) + 4\sin^2(t)}dt = 2dt$$

And $\mathbf{n}(t)$:
$$\mathbf{n}(t) = \mathbf{R}\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{R}\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t) =\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\ 
 -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-2\sin(t)\\
2\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2\cos(t)\\
2\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hope this answer your question, in some way :)

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Pedroth. I upvoted it. I still to have to meditated on it a bit